# SQL Server - index scan where index seek expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm attempting to remove an index scan, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it a seek with my current understanding. I've looked at other posts throughout SO that suggest the ordering of the columns in the index need to be correct, and to my current understanding, they *seem* to be correct, but I could be completely off. And maybe the order isn't the answer at all.

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @ChartActions TABLE
(
    InValue INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO @ChartActions
VALUES
(73),
(74),
(75);

with cteGroupedChartActivity AS (
    SELECT MAX(ActivityId) as ActivityId
    FROM Activity
    JOIN UserDocument  ON Activity.ActionObjectId = UserDocument.UserDocumentId
    WHERE   Action IN (SELECT * FROM @ChartActions)
    GROUP BY UserDocument.DocumentTypeId,CAST(Activity.DateCreated AS DATE)
)
select * from cteGroupedChartActivity
```

I believe it may be worth mentioning that Activity.ActionObjectId is not a foreign key reference to UserDocument.UserDocumentId--it is a loose column that we use to store other primary key values that we then link to conditionally based on Activity.Action.

Current PK/indices:

```
CONSTRAINT [pk_UserDocuments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserDocumentId] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_ud_dtid] ON [dbo].[UserDocument]
(
    [DocumentTypeId] ASC
)
```

DocumentTypeId is int not null.

The query plan ultimately yields:

- **Hash Match (Aggregate) 12%** <=
- **Hash Match (Inner Join) 57%** <=
- **Index Scan (NonClustered) [UserDocument].[ix_ud_dtid] 28%**

The inner join hash match also spills over into tempdb. Not sure if that's useful information or not.

When mousing over the index scan, the actual number of records is 468,392.

Any thoughts? I'd show images but I don't have the rep. I would be happy to provide any more info needed in any way that I can.

**Edit 1:**

Table structures are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Activity]
(
    [ActivityId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UID] [int] NULL,
    [Action] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActionObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PID] [int] NULL,
    [Data] [varchar](1024) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDocument]
(
    [UserDocumentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentTypeId] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Indices on dbo.Activity table:

```
CONSTRAINT [pk_Activity] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ActivityId] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_a_a__inc__aoid_dc_pid] ON [dbo].[Activity]
(
    [Action] ASC
)
INCLUDE
(
    [ActionObjectId],
    [DateCreated],
    [PID]
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_a_pid_uid_a_aoid_dc_d] ON [dbo].[Activity]
(
    [PID] ASC
)
INCLUDE
(
    [UID],
    [Action],
    [ActionObjectId],
    [DateCreated],
    [Data]
)
```

Comment: Hard to say without table structures and more details on the plan. A guess would be that the cost of the pk lookup after finding the row in the ix_ud_dtid index is considered higher than the index scan. That being said, this question may find a better audience on dba.stackexchange.

Comment: Are there any indices on the Activity table? They are just as important.

Comment: @TheVedge - I have added table structure to see if it helps to paint a clearer picture. I've seen some pretty good answers here on SO, but if I don't really have any luck here, I'll head over to DBA as well.

Comment: @RogerF.Wolf - I've edited the post to include indices from the Activity table as well.

Comment: @Mark Looking at this, it could be a combination of multiple factors. I would say that the ix_ud_dtid is used to save some cycle on the grouping. Is the Activity table much bigger than UserDocument, as far as row count goes? Also, that looks of it, it would give you a bigger bang for your buck to index Activity.ActivityObjectId

Comment: @TheVedge - The Activity table contains 491,900 records while the UserDocument table contains 467,232 records. I think Roger was saying the same thing--to index the ActionObjectId. Although I did try, and perhaps I'm not doing it properly, but it still seemed to do a scan. I will respond in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather start with indices on `dbo.Activity` table. None of the existing ones is suitable for this query, but one of these should to the trick:

```
(Action, ActionObjectId)
(Action, ActionObjectId) include (DateCreated)
(Action, ActionObjectId, DateCreated)
```

Your indices on `dbo.UserDocument` table are just fine.

Oh, yes, and there is no sense in casting `datetime` column into `date` while sorting. It will not give you anything useful, but will definitely ruin any benefit from an index you may possibly have.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hopeful that the indices on dbo.UserDocument were good--they seemed to be okay. I hadn't realized that having an improper index on the dbo.Activity would cause a scan on dbo.UserDocument. I did try both the second and third indices provided in the answer, but I had no luck; there's still a scan on dbo.UserDocument. I also updated the statistics on those tables, just in case. I cast datetime to date to remove the time factor so the grouping will work only on the date and not consider the time. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @Mark, oops I didn't noticed that it's grouping, not ordering. Casting to a different data type usually results in ignoring all indices on such field. Try to remove `cast()`, just to check whether the plan will straighten up. Also, you might find useful to index the table variable: `DECLARE @ChartActions TABLE (InValue int primary key);`.

Comment: I had suspected that casting it may cause it to ignore the index so I did try removing the cast as well. Still no luck, it seems. It still tries to do an index scan on UserDocument using ix_ud_dtid. I also made InValue in @ChartActions a PK. (It also does a clustered index scan on that, but I suspect it's just the small amount of rows.)

Comment: @Mark, check the SQL Server index suggestions regarding these two tables. I suspect you might have oversimplified your query. Also, how much of `dbo.UserDocument` table is actually affected by it? If it's about 10-20%% or more, the index scan is actually a better strategy.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think that maybe it's just SQL Server deciding that it's faster to do a scan. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I would index ActionObjectId  before Action, if only because the Inner Join seems to be the slowest part of the query.

Comment: @TheVedge, actually yes, it might work. Judging by the logic behind the schema, `ActionObjectId` probably has much better selectivity, which is crucial for composite indices. Mea culpa.

Comment: @RogerF.Wolf Indexing Action first could've changed the order of the join, making better use of UserDocument index, so it was probably worth it to try both!

Comment: @TheVedge - I created another index where ActionObjectId came first, and the query plan actually chose to use that one over the others. But there's still a scan on the UserDocument (I'm unsure if that's even a real problem anymore).

Comment: @Mark that was going to be my next question: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @TheVedge - We have this query in our production environment that seems to time out, but rather inconsistently. I broke the query down into pieces and have been trying to optimize each piece to see if it would help improve performance. But lately it hasn't been timing out and we haven't been able to reliably reproduce it since so maybe this scanning isn't part of the problem.